# Can I have font smoothing on an external display, but not on MacBook Pro's own retina screen?

Tags: macos, display, font

Font smoothing appears to be applied to all screens but I prefer to have the fonts on my retina screen non-smoothed.

However, non-smoothed fonts on the standard 1080p monitor I attach look awful.

Can I tell macOS to turn it on only for the attached monitor? Maybe by hacking the monitor color profile?

Comment: same problem! any solution?, with a pc it looks great!